# Should I watch the TV series before playing Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have purchased the Game of Thrones (Telltale game, all episodes) but haven't got around to watching the TV series.  I understand that the game includes characters from the TV series.

Do I need to watch up to a specific episode of the TV series before playing the game (to understand the game's plot)?

Will I encounter any spoilers by playing the game before watching the TV series?

Comment: To potential close voters: He's asking this question from a spoiler standpoint, or from an understanding standpoint. This isn't actually soliciting opinions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Telltale's Game of Thrones begins at the end of Season 3 and includes major spoilers for episodes up to and including Season 4 Episode 2 "The Lion and the Rose". I would strongly recommend watching at least up to this point before playing.

The game also assumes the viewer is somewhat familiar with the Game of Thrones setting and its characters.

Comment: +1, I don't think the scenes would have the same emotional impact if you're not familiar with the locations and characters, especially Ramsay Snow.

Comment: I think this actually cuts both ways. In some sense knowing things from the show actually detracts from the game. For example, you can vow bloody revenge on one particular character, but from the show you know that's an empty threat.

Comment: But that really depends on how they made the game.  It's a complete shot in a dark since some games are just absolute trash compared to their counterpart, and vice versa (all the fighting game movies... ugh...)